# first click not working in jquery but on second click deplicate data

Tags: jquery

This is my codes am trying to send data from `bootstrap` model but if I click on submit button at first time it is not working it working on second click and delicate the rows to insert in database? Whats wrong with my codes?

```
function sendAppointment() {
  $('#send_appointment').click(function() {
    // console.log("ndatambuka i know....");
    let doctor_id = $('#doctor`enter code here`_id').val(),
      hospital_id = $('#hospital_id').val(),
      start_time = $('#start_time').val(),
      end_time = $('#end_time').val(),
      service_name = $('#service_name').val(),
      amount = $('#amount').val(),
      phone = $('#phone').val();
    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
      url: "server.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        send_appointment: 1,
        doctor_id: doctor_id,
        hospital_id: hospital_id,
        start_time: start_time,
        end_time: end_time,
        service_name: service_name,
        amount: amount,
        phone: phone
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(dataResult) {
        console.log(dataResult);
        var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
        if (dataResult.statusCode == 200) {
          $("#success").show();
          $('#success').html('Appointment made  successfully !');
          setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = "availability_doctor.php";
          }, 6000)
        } else if (dataResult.statusCode == 201) {
          $("#error").show();
          $('#error').html('failed to make an appointment!');
        }

      }
    });
  });

}
```

Comment: How are you calling `sendAppointment()`?

Comment: If you call `sendAppointment` on click, then your first click adds event listener and only on second click it's triggered. If so, unwrap code from event listener

Comment: this is how i call function<button type="button" id="send_appointment" onclick="sendAppointment();" class="btn btn-primary">Comfirm Appointment</button>

Comment: thanks you are right   $('#send_appointment').click(function(){  }); i remove this line of codes now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call sendAppointment on click, then your first click adds event listener and only on second click it's triggered. If so, unwrap code from event listener

i remove
$('#send_appointment').click(function(){});

and the problem was resolved